# Laravel Livewire loading after Alpine.js after Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire, alpine.js, laravel-jetstream

I get the following error with a modal component on the profile page:

Console:

`Uncaught TypeError: window.Livewire.find(...) is undefined`

After the page is fully loaded, I can access livewire in the console:

`window.Livewire.find(...)`

It seems that Livewire ist loading before Alpine.js *or* it`s an Error in Jetstream (Delete Account Modal)

Updated packages from/to:

composer.json

```
"laravel/jetstream": "^3.2" -> "^4.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^2.11" -> "^v3.0",
```

package.json

```
"alpinejs": "^3.0.6" -> "^3.13.2",
```

delete-user-form.blade.php

```
<div class="mt-5">
    <x-danger-button wire:click="confirmUserDeletion" wire:loading.attr="disabled">
        {{ __('Delete Account') }}
    </x-danger-button>
</div>

<!-- Delete User Confirmation Modal -->
<x-dialog-modal wire:model.live="confirmingUserDeletion">
    ...
    content
    ...
</x-dialog-modal>
```

app.blade.php

```
<head>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    @vite(['resources/scss/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js', 'node_modules/trix/dist/trix.esm.min.js', 'node_modules/trix/dist/trix.css'])

    <!-- Styles -->
    @livewireStyles
</head>
<body class="font-sans antialiased">
    ...
    content
    ...
    @stack('modals')
    @livewireScripts
</body>
```

I tried to move the `@livewireScripts` from before the `</body>` tag, it did not work either (and it is not a solution I would want to use).

Comment: I think this will solve your issue @livewireScripts(['defer' => true]).

Comment: @KhayamKhan Thank you, but unfortunately its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Livewire 3, you shouldn't be installing AlpineJS manually to begin with. The [installation guide](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart#install-livewire) is very clear about it. Removing `alpinejs` from your `package.json` should fix your issues (but only if you're using Livewire 3).

If you are using plugins, and need to manually boot AlpineJS, then you should take a look at [this section](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation#manually-bundling-livewire-and-alpine)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. I migrated from 2 to 3, so it works perfectly now.