# How to move Alpine.store methods from simple template (loaded from CDN) to Laravel with Livewire (Vite)

Tags: laravel, vite, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I made a simple website [template](https://github.com/devhubpl/Sidebar-template)  based on tailwindcss and alpinejs, adding them as CDN. I use Alpine.store there to extend/hide the sidebar with a click. It works ok, as I expected, with no errors in console.
Now I want to move this template to laravel app. I added the html elements to the blade files. tailwindcss and alpinejs are installed and built with vite.
In the *resources/js/app.js* file I added the lines:

```
import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.store('sidebar', {
     open: false,
     hide: false,
     visible: false,

     toggle(value) {
         this[value] = ! this[value]
     },
     toggleOpen() {
         this.open = ! this.open
     },
     toggleHide() {
         this.hide = ! this.hide
     }
})

Alpine.start();
```

Generally, click actions work, but I have a lot of errors in the console, when loading the page and with each click.

```
Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'open')

Expression: "[
         ($store.sidebar.open ? 'md:w-60' : ''),
         ($store.sidebar.hide ? '-translate-x-full': ''),
         ($store.sidebar.visible ? '!block hover:!w-60': '')
     ]"

Alpine Expression Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toggleHide')

Expression: "$store.sidebar.toggleHide()"
```

If I change *$store.sidebar.open* to *Alpine.store('sidebar')* in the blade files, there are no errors, but clicks do not work.

Enviroment:

- Laravel 10 (with Breeze UI)
- Livewire 3
- Vite

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77920248/laravel-livewire-loading-after-alpine-js-after-update#answer-77952955) and that's the point. I will test this more but it looks ok now.